# What is the probability that Pat wins?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Sam and Pat are playing foosball. When they begin, the score is 0­-0. To make things interesting, if the score ever becomes tied, it is instantly reset to 0-­0. Starting from any score, the probability that Sam gets the next point is 1/3. 
The game stops when one player’s score reaches 2.

**Answer:-**

Denote by (x, y) the score of Sam and Pat respectively, a Markov chain that describes the game is :

[image]

The probability that Pat wins is the probability that we get absorbed to the state (0, 2).

Now, how can I Setting up the equations?, and solve for a(1,0), a(0,0) and a(0,1)

**How it needs to be solved next?**

found this question on MIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the probability that Pat wins from $(1,0), (0,0), (0,1)$ respectively.  Looking at $(0,1)$ you have $c=\frac 23 + \frac 13b$.  Write the equations that come from the other two states and you have three equations in three unknowns.